# formset for multiple form

Tags: python, django

ok i am following the formset. Pretty much i understand that formset is for multiple form.

so this example i just want take four values same time but the ouput in html have only one form is showing.

Shall i want to make extra filed like this `<input id="your_name" type="text" name="your_name">` or django will do the rest or any other way to do that.?

models.py

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

forms.py

```
class ArticleForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField()
    #pub_date = forms.DateField()

ArticleFormSet = formset_factory(ArticleForm, extra=4, validate_max=True)
```

views.py

```
def book(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = ArticleForm(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            new = Article()
            new.title = request.POST.get('title', None)
            #new.pub_date = request.POST.get('pub_date', None)
            new.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('firstapp.views.book'))
    else:
        formset = ArticleForm()
    return render_to_response('get.html',{'formset': formset}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

And the html look like this

```
<form method="post" action="">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ formset.management_form }}
  <table>
    {% for form in formset %}
    {{ form }}
    {% endfor %}
  </table>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view you are binding `formset` to an `ArticleForm`, not to an `ArticleFormSet`. Also you are only creating one single `Article` from it, and you're not even using the `form` properly (ie: you're getting the `title` directly from `request.POST` instead of getting it from your form's `cleaned_data`). Your view code should look something like this (caveat: untested and possibly buggy code, but at least you'll get the picture).

```
def book(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = ArticleFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            for data in formset.cleaned_data:
                Article.objects.create(title=data['title'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('firstapp.views.book'))
    else:
        formset = ArticleFormSet()
    return render_to_response('get.html',{'formset': formset}, 
                              context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

As a last point, I strongly suggest you have a look at `ModelForms`.

Comment: Super.. Exactly what i want..!

Comment: but if i want to upload the imagefile or i am using filefield then what should i do?

Comment: @gello: a `ModelForm` (and `ModelFormSet`) will take care of your image / file fields - assuming they are defined on the model, not removed from the modelform, and that you have the "multipart/form-data" enctype set in your (html) form tag and pass `request.FILES` as the second positional argument to your form / formset.